# How to load multiple AndroidViewModel in a single activity to access LiveData which is returning value from multiple table using Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am developing an E-Commerce app in android where I have to create multiple Table, insert data on it and fetch data in activity/fragments from that table (Load value in Spinner, run condition based sub query etc.). For that I declared 2 tables. Address, Bank like below

**Bank.java**

```
@Entity
public class Bank {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String bankId;
    public String bankName;
    public String bankType;

    public Bank() {
    }

    public String getBankId() {
        return bankId;
    }

    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }

    public String getBankType() {
        return bankType;
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String state;
    public String district;
    public String block;
    public String id_panchayat;
    public String panchayat;

    public Address() {
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public String getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public String getId_panchayat() {
        return id_panchayat;
    }

    public String getPanchayat() {
        return panchayat;
    }
}
```

And the Dao class for these two tables are:

**BankDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface BankDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insertSingleBank (Bank bank);

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insertMultipleBank (List<Bank> bankList);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Bank")
    LiveData<List<Bank>> getAllBank();

    @Query("SELECT bankName FROM Bank")
    List<String> getAllBankData ();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Bank WHERE bankName = :bankName")
    Bank getBankSubData (String bankName);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Bank")
    void deleteBank();
}
```

**AddressDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface AddressDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insertSingleAddress(Address address);

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insertMultipleAddress(List<Address> addressList);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Address")
    LiveData<List<Address>> getAllAddress();

    @Query("SELECT state FROM Address")
    List<String> getAllStateList();

    @Query("SELECT district FROM Address WHERE state = :state")
    List<String> getDistrictListAll(String state);

    @Query("SELECT block FROM Address WHERE state = :state AND district = :district")
    List<String> getBlockListAll(String state, String district);

    @Query("SELECT panchayat FROM Address WHERE state = :state AND district = :district AND block = :block")
    List<String> getPanchayatListAll(String state, String district, String block);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Address")
    void deleteAddress();
}
```

And the ViewModel for those two classes are

**AddressModel.java**

```
public class AddressModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private RoomDatabaseHelper roomDatabase;
    private final LiveData<List<Address>> getAllAddress;

    public AddressModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        roomDatabase = RoomDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.getApplication());
        getAllAddress = roomDatabase.daoAddress().getAllAddress();
    }

    public void insertSingleAddress(Address address) {
        new InsertSingleAddressAsyncTask(roomDatabase).execute(address);
    }

    private static class InsertSingleAddressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Address, Void, Void> {

        private RoomDatabaseHelper db;

        InsertSingleAddressAsyncTask(RoomDatabaseHelper userDatabase) {
            db = userDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Address...params) {
            db.daoAddress().insertSingleAddress(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void insertMultipleAddress(List<Address> registrationList) {
        new InsertMultipleAddressAsyncTask(roomDatabase).execute(registrationList);
    }

    private static class InsertMultipleAddressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Address>, Void, Void> {

        private RoomDatabaseHelper db;

        InsertMultipleAddressAsyncTask(RoomDatabaseHelper userDatabase) {
            db = userDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Address>...params) {
            db.daoAddress().insertMultipleAddress(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LiveData<List<Address>> getAllAddress() {
        return getAllAddress;
    }
}
```

**BankModel.java**

```
public class BankModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private RoomDatabaseHelper roomDatabase;
    private final LiveData<List<Bank>> getAllBank;

    public BankModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        roomDatabase = RoomDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.getApplication());
        getAllBank = roomDatabase.daoBank().getAllBank();
    }

    public void insertSingleBank(Bank bank) {
        new InsertSingleBankAsyncTask(roomDatabase).execute(bank);
    }

    private static class InsertSingleBankAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Bank, Void, Void> {

        private RoomDatabaseHelper db;

        InsertSingleBankAsyncTask(RoomDatabaseHelper userDatabase) {
            db = userDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Bank...params) {
            db.daoBank().insertSingleBank(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void insertMultipleBank(List<Bank> registrationList) {
        new InsertMultipleBankAsyncTask(roomDatabase).execute(registrationList);
    }

    private static class InsertMultipleBankAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<Bank>, Void, Void> {

        private RoomDatabaseHelper db;

        InsertMultipleBankAsyncTask(RoomDatabaseHelper userDatabase) {
            db = userDatabase;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Bank>...params) {
            db.daoBank().insertMultipleBank(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LiveData<List<Bank>> getAllBank() {
        return getAllBank;
    }
}
```

The RoomDatabase class is

**RoomDatabaseHelper.java**

```
@Database(entities = {Address.class, Bank.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class RoomDatabaseHelper extends RoomDatabase {

    private static RoomDatabaseHelper sInstance;

    public static synchronized RoomDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), RoomDatabaseHelper.class, "DemoTable").build();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public abstract AddressDao daoAddress();

    public abstract BankDao daoBank();
}
```

and in my Fragment:

```
BankModel bankModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BankModel.class);
AddressModel addressModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddressModel.class);
```

Now according to documentation to access the `getAllBank()` and `getAllAddress()` from both Model class I have to define like this

```
addressModel.getAllAddress().observe(mActivity, new Observer<List<Address>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Address> addressList) {
    }
});

addressModel.getAllBank().observe(mActivity, new Observer<List<Bank>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(final List<Bank> bankList) {
    }
});
```

now both method are `AsyncTask` like thing. So on activity load I cant change the UI related thing. I have to place the whole UI under `onChange`. How can I access both observer at the same. Cause nested observer is not the right solution. And also I need many complex database query. So for that I have to define so many observer or is there any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ViewModels should be used as helpers for fragments or activities, to retrieve and process the required data for the views. Thus, one Activity/Fragment should have one viewmodel. And here you use them as some sort of repositories.

If you still wanna use them like that: 
`How can I access both observer at the same`

on both onChanged call a method like `tryUpdateUi()` where you check if both `getAllBank().getValue()` and `getAllAddress().getValue()` are not null. If so, you can do the updating/calculations etc.

Although I would prefer doing this check and the data processing in the ViewModel, using another LiveData to pass the processed models to Fragment. It can be achieved with MediatorLiveData, [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData)